# ImproperlyConfigured at / Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "classname-detail"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ClassSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):   #Once I add the Hyperlinked it raises above exception.
    class Meta:
        model = Classname
        fields = ('url', 'class_name',)

class SectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sectionname
        fields = ('url', 'class_name', 'section_name')

class TeacherSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teachername
        fields = ('url', 'classname', 'secname', 'teachname')

class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendancename
        fields = ('url', 'teacher_name', 'date', 'intime', 'outtime')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #DRF urls start from here...
    url(r'^$', views.api_root),
    #url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    #url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
    url(r'^class/$', views.ClassList.as_view(), name='classname-list'),
    url(r'^class/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClassDetail.as_view(), name='classname-detail'),
    url(r'^section/$', views.SectionList.as_view(), name='sectionname-list'),
    url(r'^section/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SectionDetail.as_view(), name='sectionname-detail'),
    url(r'^teach/$', views.TeacherList.as_view(), name='teachername-list'),
    url(r'^teach/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TeacherDetail.as_view(), name='teachername-detail'),
    url(r'^attend/$', views.AttendanceList.as_view(), name='attendance-list'),
    url(r'^attend/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AttendanceDetail.as_view(), name='attendance-detail'),
```

]

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .serializers import ClassSerializer, SectionSerializer,   TeacherSerializer, AttendanceSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

@api_view(('GET',))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'class':reverse('student:classname-list', request=request, format=format),
        'section':reverse('student:sectionname-list', request=request, format=format),
        'teacher':reverse('student:teachername-list', request=request, format=format),
        'attendance':reverse('student:attendancename-list', request=request, format=format)
})

class ClassnameList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Classname.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class ClassnameDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Classname.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class SectionnameList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Sectionname.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SectionSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class SectionnameDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Sectionname.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SectionSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class TeachernameList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Teachername.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class TeachernameDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Teachername.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class AttendancenameList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Attendancename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendanceSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class AttendancenameDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Attendancename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendanceSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/stu/class/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'student')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in get
  241.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  47.         return Response(serializer.data)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  622.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  217.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  572.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  572.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  439.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py" in to_representation
  272.             raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /stu/class/
Exception Value: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "classname-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

I'm following DRF tutorial to make my demo app serializable. I've got a problem when I'm trying to add Hyperlinked in my serializers, it throws above exception.

I don't know why it does so? as I follow proper URL namespacing conventions.

Please help me to resolve it.....

Comment: In your `urls.py`, you dont have `classname-detail`, you have `classdet`

Comment: Thanks! for your feedback. I tried this but it again raises same exception...

Comment: I've changed `'classdet'` to `'classname-detail'`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is with my project level urls. As I've removed the `'namespacing'` argument from my project level url which includes my app like
`'url(r'^stu/$', include('student:app'))'`. As `'classname-detail'` can't include implicitly `'namespacing'` argument so it raises above exception.